# How to determine thousands separator in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

In order for [toLocaleString](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toLocaleString) to work, the browser/JavaScript must know the user's locale and whether or not [the specific locale uses "," or "."](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decimal_mark#Hindu.E2.80.93Arabic_numeral_system) for a thousands separator. Is it possible to access this data so that we can determine what the thousands separator is?

If not, we can use a function like this...

```
var thousandsSeparator = (function(){
    if (typeof Number.prototype.toLocaleString === 'function') {
        var num = 1000;
        var numStr = num.toLocaleString();
        if (numStr.length == 5) {
            return numStr.substr(1, 1);
        }
    }
    return ","; // fall-back
})();
```

...but it feels like an unnecessary hack.

Comment: You call it a hack.  I call it elegant :-)

Answer (score 5):

A little further digging and I found [Intl.NumberFormat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/NumberFormat). I think this is more elegant...

```
const thousandsSeparator = (function(){
    if (typeof Intl !== 'object') {
        return ','; // fallback
    }
    // Get the formatting object for your locale
    const numFormat = new Intl.NumberFormat();
    // The resolved.pattern will be something like "#,##0.###"
    return numFormat.resolved.pattern.substr(1,1);
})();
```

Or if you really need it ultra-concise...

```
const thousandsSeparator = (Intl) ? (new Intl.NumberFormat()).resolved.pattern.substr(1,1) : ",";
```

**Compatibility warning (2015):**

- The `Intl` object may not be supported in Safari for some reason -- http://caniuse.com/#feat=internationalization -- despite it being part of standard ECMAScript.
- While the `Intl` object may exist in some ECMAScript-standard browsers, **the code above will only work in Chrome**.
- Sadly Firefox 40 and IE 11 currently do not have a `resolved` property in `numFormat`.

An elegant cross-browser solution is still out there...

**Update (2021):**

`Intl`, and `numFormat.resolved` may have better browser support in non-Chrome browsers now. See comments for latest information.

Comment: Nice find. I'd not heard of `Intl` before now.

Comment: As of 2020, Intl is much more widely supported. [Can I Use Intl: NumberFormat](https://caniuse.com/#search=NumberFormat)

Comment: Is `numFormat.resolved` still a thing? I can't find any information on it, and it's coming back undefined for me in Chrome.

Answer (score 1):

Easy, I guess. This should help you to start with this ES6 solution

```js
function getThousandSeparator(locale){
  const mapperRE = /(.{1})\d{3}(\D)\d$/,
    digitRE = /\d/,
    formattedValue = (new Intl.NumberFormat(locale?? navigator.language)).format(1000.1);
  let [_,thousand, decimal] = mapperRE.exec(formattedValue) ?? [null,null,null];
  //In case the captured position is number it means there's no thousand separator
  if(digitRE.test(thousand)) 
    thousand = '';
  return {thousand, decimal}
}
```

Comment: Using `\d` does not work with all locales (f. ex. with `ar-EG`); we could use unicode  regex instead (`\p{Nd}`).

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `formatToParts()` function ([MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/NumberFormat/formatToParts)) on `Intl.NumberFormat` to try to get the separator:

```
const separator = new Intl.NumberFormat().formatToParts(1000)[1].value
```

Comment: That might not work for any locale, e. g. in case there's no group separator in it. A more reliable way would be:

`new Intl.NumberFormat().formatToParts(1000).find((part) => part.type === "group")?.value ?? ""`